# How To set the second node of xpath

Tags: java, xpath

This is an example of my xml. How can I set the path for stationary. For the First List I set my path as `Listing/ListingName[1]` and it works. How about the second one? The stationary path. I tried `Listing/ListingName[last()]` but it did not work. Can anyone help me? I am using java.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Listing>

       <ListingType>First List</ListingType>

       <ListingName>Book</ListingName>

</Listing>

<Listing>

        <ListingType>Second List</ListingType>

        <ListingName>Stationary</ListingName>

</Listing>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the ListingName of the last Listing, so last() should be on Listing, no?

```
Listing[last()]/ListingName
```

Your first expression returns the first ListningName of all Listing objects, but you probably extract only the first result.

Comment: Got It Thanks..Sorry My Mistakes

Comment: @NurWafiqa: if this is the answer to your question, you should accept it.

Comment: oh,.. I didn't know about that restriction :blush: sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You need the second `Listing` element, so: `Listing[2]/ListingName`

Answer (score 1):

Or, even this:

```
(Listing/ListingName)[last()]
```

**EDIT:**

Here, the predicate `[last()]` applies to the sequence of nodes selected in the xpath `Listing/ListingName`, selecting only the last `ListingName`.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.